# How to print only last column for xlsx sheet using Node.js

Tags: node.js, json, xlsx

```
const reader = require('xlsx')

const file = reader.readFile('./Excel Template 3.xlsx')

const sheets = file.SheetNames
console.log(sheets.length)
for(let i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++)
{
 
var data = reader.utils.sheet_to_json(
        file.Sheets[file.SheetNames[i]])
  

}
console.log(data)
delete data.Numbers
console.log(data)
```

I printed the excel sheet using node.js but I want always to delete last column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (i=0; i<data.length;i++){
  for(y=0; y<data.length;y++){
    console.log(y)
    delete data[y].Numbers
    
  }
}


console.log(data)
```